# Is there anyway monero can be investigated

Tags: mymonero

I am tasked with an assignment on monero cryptocurrency and one of the points I need to cover is “how can the currency be investigated”. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What is the context?  The question by itself doesn't really make sense.  Is the question how to "research" the Monero?  To "investigate" connotes something different than to "research."  Usually people and/or events are investigated.  To investigate is "To observe or inquire into in detail; examine systematically."  The software is open source, so you could look at source code.  You could look at a block explorer, or ask the community, like on IRC or reddit... or here!  But, again, are you researching?  Or what is meant by "investigated?"

Answer (score 1):

Monero is a cryptocurrency for which the reference implementation is open source, available at https://github.com/monero-project/monero. Anyone may read the source, and modify it to suit their own ends, provided the (BSD) license is respected (which basically means don't be an asshole and pretend you wrote it all yourself).

You will need some basic competency in C++ to read and understand the source.